# Customizing TFS Web Portal Capacity (Work Details)

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Long story short, someone changed something in our TFS a few years ago and now I am trying to undo what they did.  I have spent the last week or so combing the internet and digging through the TFS XML files trying to figure out how they did this.

This is what I need (Work Details in hours)

[image: This is in hours]

and not like this (Work Details in points)

[image: This is in points]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You need to do the reverse operation described here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2012/09/24/tfsagile-pm-configuring-so-your-tasks-are-estimated-in-story-points/). Basically exporting the process configuration and changing the Unit specified in the formatting of the remaining work field.

Change:

```
<TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" 
type="RemainingWork" format="{0} sp" />
```

back to:

```
<TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" 
type="RemainingWork" format="{0} h" />
```

To change it export the Process Configuration:

```
witadmin.exe exportprocessconfig /collection:http://SERVERNAME:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection 
             /p:PROJECTNAME  /f:.\ProcessConfiguration.xml
```

apply the above change and import it again:

```
witadmin.exe importprocessconfig  /collection:http://SERVERNAME:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection 
                /p:PROJECTNAME  /f:.\ProcessConfiguration.xml
```

Comment: Thank you so much, my head has been spinning for a week.  I have learned more about TFS each day but could not figure this one out.

Answer (score 1):

Look at 
[WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACEvn.png)

Use this command to export the common ProcessConfiguration

```
witadmin.exe exportcommonprocessconfig /collection:http://SERVERNAME:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection 
         /p:PROJECTNAME  /f:.\processconfig.xml
```

Change Points to h in this line

```
<TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" type="RemainingWork" format="{0} points" />
```

And use this command to import the common ProcessConfiguration

```
witadmin.exe importcommonprocessconfig /collection:http://SERVERNAME:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection 
         /p:PROJECTNAME  /f:.\processconfig.xml
```

Comment: You got there eventually. Be careful though, you started with what SO call a link only answer.